# Polars: Select first (or any) non-null column value row-wise

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

How can we select first (or any) non-null struct from polars dataframe to new column?

**Input data:**

```
structs_a = [
    {"a_key_1": 1, "a_key_2": "a" },
    {"a_key_1": None, "a_key_2": None }
]
structs_b = [
    {"b_key_1": None, "b_key_2": None },
    {"b_key_1": "b", "b_key_2": 2 }
]
df = pl.DataFrame([structs_a, structs_b])
df
```

```
┌─────────────┬─────────────┐
│ column_0    ┆ column_1    │
│ ---         ┆ ---         │
│ struct[2]   ┆ struct[2]   │
╞═════════════╪═════════════╡
│ {1,"a"}     ┆ {null,null} │
│ {null,null} ┆ {"b",2}     │
└─────────────┴─────────────┘
```

What I've tried so far:
Concatenating values to list and dropping nulls, but for reasons I yet have to understand this results in **empty** list of struct**[4]**

```
df.with_columns(
             pl.concat_list([
                 "column_0",
                 "column_1",
             ]).arr.eval(pl.element().drop_nulls()).alias('final_column'))
```

**My result:**

```
┌─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ column_0    ┆ column_1    ┆ final_column    │
│ ---         ┆ ---         ┆ ---             │
│ struct[2]   ┆ struct[2]   ┆ list[struct[4]] │
╞═════════════╪═════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ {1,"a"}     ┆ {null,null} ┆ []              │
│ {null,null} ┆ {"b",2}     ┆ []              │
└─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

**Desirable result:**

```
┌─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ column_0    ┆ column_1    ┆ final_column    │
│ ---         ┆ ---         ┆ ---             │
│ struct[2]   ┆ struct[2]   ┆ struct[2]       │
╞═════════════╪═════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ {1,"a"}     ┆ {null,null} ┆ {1,"a"}         │ <- Non-null value from column_0
│ {null,null} ┆ {"b",2}     ┆ {"b",2}         │ <- Non-null value from column_1
└─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

**UPD:**
Probably should experiment with [coalesce](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.coalesce.html) but direct implementation did not result as desired:

```
df.with_columns(
             pl.coalesce([
                 "column_0",
                 "column_1",
             ]).alias('final_column'))
```

one more undesired result:

```
┌─────────────┬─────────────┬───────────────────────┐
│ column_0    ┆ column_1    ┆ final_column          │
│ ---         ┆ ---         ┆ ---                   │
│ struct[2]   ┆ struct[2]   ┆ struct[4]             │
╞═════════════╪═════════════╪═══════════════════════╡
│ {1,"a"}     ┆ {null,null} ┆ {null,null,null,null} │
│ {null,null} ┆ {"b",2}     ┆ {null,null,"b",2}     │
└─────────────┴─────────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

Comment: The lists are empty, because every strut then includes a null:

`df.select([pl.concat_list(pl.all()).alias("final_column")])` returns ```┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ final_column                        │
│ ---                                 │
│ list[struct[4]]                     │
╞═════════════════════════════════════╡
│ [{1,"a",null,null}, {null,null,n... │
│ [{null,null,null,null}, {null,nu... │
└─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: If you check `.arr.eval(pl.element().is_null())` it does seem to know what should be dropped. It seems like something is not "struct aware". The `.coalesce` works if they are non-struct columns.

Answer (score 1):

#### Introduction

This question so concerning to dictionaries. I have been testing different ways to create a solution for your question, i got a fast solution that works well where i get the result you are searching for.

If you want to filter by null values, as you are using dictionaries you have to go deep into the keys and values of that dictionaries because if you are checking for nulls or nas values you´ll check the rows values.

#### First approach

A way that is going to works for sure is to iterate the dataframe and check the values inside of it, you can do it in some different ways i used `shape` function.

```
new_column = [] #Define the array variable

for i in range(df.shape[0]): #iterate over rows
    for j in range(df.shape[1]): #iterate over columns
        value = df.at[i, j] # get cell value
        values = value.values() # get the values from the cell value (Inside dictionary value)
        if not None in values: # check if there is some None values in the cell
            new_column.append(value) #Add the cell value into the array
      
df['final_column'] = new_column #Create the new column using the array with new values
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
    0   1   final_column
0   {'a_key_1': 1, 'a_key_2': 'a'}  {'a_key_1': None, 'a_key_2': None}  {'a_key_1': 1, 'a_key_2': 'a'}
1   {'b_key_1': None, 'b_key_2': None}  {'b_key_1': 'b', 'b_key_2': 2}  {'b_key_1': 'b', 'b_key_2': 2}
```

[image: Output image of first aprroach]

#### Second approach

Iterate by the DF in a different way

```
new_column = [] #Define the array variable

for rowIndex, row in df.iterrows(): #iterate over rows
    for columnIndex, value in row.items(): # iterate over columns
        values = value.values() # get the values from the cells
        if not None in values: # check if there is some None values in the cell
            new_column.append(value) #Add the cell value into the array
      
df6['final_column'] = new_column #Create the new column using the array with new values
```

This method give the same corret result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution and efforts! It definitely works, but due to dataset size and implementation approach I'm still looking for a polars-based solution

Comment: Good to know, i´ll check and if i can give a polars-based solution i´ll post it. Good luck anyway!